# How to customize Yoast Schema Breadcrumbs output in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, schema, breadcrumbs, yoast

By using a code snippet I try to remove a schema output from Yoast for breadcrumbs but I can't seem to fix it. This is the code provided by Yoast SEO:

```
// functions.php
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_graph_pieces', 'remove_breadcrumbs_from_schema', 11, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpseo_schema_webpage', 'remove_breadcrumbs_property_from_webpage', 11, 1 );

/**
 * Removes the breadcrumb graph pieces from the schema collector.
 *
 * @param array  $pieces  The current graph pieces.
 * @param string $context The current context.
 *
 * @return array The remaining graph pieces.
 */
function remove_breadcrumbs_from_schema( $pieces, $context ) {
    return \array_filter( $pieces, function( $piece ) {
        return ! $piece instanceof \Yoast\WP\SEO\Generators\Schema\Breadcrumb;
    } );
}
```

This is the snippet I use:

```
function remove_breadcrumbs_from_schema( $pieces, $context ) {
    return \array_filter( $pieces, function( $piece ) {
        // Modify the condition to exclude the specific listitem based on its name
        return ! (
            $piece instanceof \Yoast\WP\SEO\Generators\Schema\ListItem &&
            $piece->name === 'Producten'
        );
    } );
}
```

(And I tried many small changes here)

This is the output and the part I want to have deleted is this "{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"name":"Producten","item":"https://ferrygogo.com/nl/winkel/"}"  in the following schema output:

```
{"@type":"BreadcrumbList","@id":"https://ferrygogo.com/nl/overtocht/eemshaven-kristiansand/#breadcrumb","itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","position":1,"name":"FerryGoGo","item":"https://ferrygogo.com/nl/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":2,"name":"Producten","item":"https://ferrygogo.com/nl/winkel/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":3,"name":"Noorwegen","item":"https://ferrygogo.com/nl/noorwegen/"},{"@type":"ListItem","position":4,"name":"Eemshaven-Kristiansand"}]}
```

I tried many things, I just want to delete the second position. So far I haven't seen results on this as I keep on seeing that listitem appearing in the schema markup in the source.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
function remove_yoast_breadcrumb_link($link_output , $link)
{
    $text_to_remove = 'Producten';

    if($link['text'] == $text_to_remove) {
      $link_output = '';
    }

    return $link_output;
}
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link' ,'remove_yoast_breadcrumb_link', 10 ,2);
```

Comment: It's working smoothly in my case.

Comment: Didn't work for me: https://prnt.sc/L0hAI6OdyjOW

Answer (score -1):

The trouble here is, the `Yoast\WP\SEO\Generators\Schema\ListItem` thingy doesn't really have a name field we can mess with directly. So, here's what we gotta do instead...

We need to play around with the `wpseo_breadcrumb_links` filter. It helps us mess around with the breadcrumb links before Yoast jumps in to generate Schema.

Here's a quick code snippet that should do the trick and cut out the second breadcrumb:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'remove_specific_breadcrumb' );

function remove_specific_breadcrumb( $links ) {
    if ( count( $links ) > 1 && $links[1]['text'] === 'Producten' ) {
        array_splice( $links, 1, 1 );
    }
    return $links;
}
```

Don't forget, add this to your functions.php file or a site-specific plugin. If you're playing with a third-party theme, make sure you're tweaking a child theme, so you don't lose your changes when the theme updates. Cheers!"

Comment: What this does is, it checks if there's more than one breadcrumb and if the second one's text is 'Producten'. If both conditions are true, it cuts out the second breadcrumb from the array.

Just a heads up, this change will affect the visible breadcrumbs and the Schema. Both are created from the same data, you see. If you only wanna change the Schema but keep the breadcrumb visible, that's gonna be a bit tricky and might involve overriding the Schema generation.